# is a .js file the easiest way to hold changeable data?

Tags: javascript

This is one of the web pages to display in (link to .js file)...

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="schedule.js">
</script>
```

And starting example of code in .js file...

```
document.write('<li><a href="http://www.xxx.com/event_detail.cfm?event_id=1922736"
target="_blank">Feb 27  Miami</a></li>');
document.write('<li><a href="http://www.xxx.com/event_detail.cfm?event_id=1887534"
target="_blank">Mar 5  Austin</a></li>');
document.write('<li><a href="http://www.xxx.com/70953" target="_blank" rel="sc8">Mar
12-13 xxx</a></li>');
```

My question is, does this make sense to do this if links need to be update, or is there a better way if the user wants to update this every few months.
Thanks, Shane

Comment: If you just have to update it every few months, why don't you just write them directly into the html page?

Comment: To be more clear, I am using this to update yearly events in a menu column to be displayed in every webpage.

Comment: ah, ok. Then I'd also go for the PHP (maybe + MySQL) variant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a server side or build time include or template system is better then foisting this off onto the client with client side JS. That way you protect search engines and users who don't run JS.

Having the lists encoded as raw HTML will work, but you might want to use a database and give a user friendly UI for the client to edit them with.

Comment: "That way you protect search engines and users who don't run JS." This part does have me concerned. Is it common?

Comment: Search engines are very common. Users who disable JS are far from unheard of (and tools such as NoScript which allow selective enabling of JS make it easier to be such a person). This isn't a problem if you [use good design principles](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/).

Comment: What exactly is the issue with search engines if you don't mind going into more detail?

Comment: They won't process the JS (so they won't see the links and thus won't follow and index them).

Comment: This post is a little old, but I have since figured php and if available access the database with UI would have been my choice. Next time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest saving it into a MySQL database and then rendering the code using PHP - way easier to program *and* easier to maintain. Also, it's better to have it in one database, if, as you say, you need to access it from different locations but still keep it synchronized.

Comment: I like the idea of doing MySQL/PHP. I will look into all the ideas everyone is giving and try to break down advantages to each.